# How to solve this copy-paste issue?

Tags: vim

Let's say you're browsing [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking) and you see the following snippet of code:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

You double-click to select the whole line, copy it and then want to insert it between the double quotes here in Vim:

```
<div onClick=""></div>
```

Well, instead of this:

```
<div onClick="_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)"></div>
```

This is what I get when I do it:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
<div onClick=""></div>
```

And it's pretty annoying. It's due to the ending line break that's inserted by OS X in the clipboard. How could I tell Vim to ignore the ending line breaks when working with one liners?

Comment: where was the cursor when you did the insert operation? if vi's already in insert mode, any characters you're inserting wouldn't affect the cursor positioning, unless the paste itself have cursor keycodes embedded.

Comment: How do you paste it? It works fine for me with `Ctrl+R`, `*`.

Comment: I usually do `i<C-v>`, however the problem is almost the same with `"+p` (the pasted line goes one line after instead of one line before the targeted line)

Comment: @MarcB Is a line break a cursor keycode? How can I see in terms of keycodes what's inside what I paste?

Comment: I use vim over ssh and I have to use `Shift+Insert` to paste from my clipboard into vim's buffers.

Comment: A double-click only selects a word. You need a triple-click to select a whole line and that selection *includes* the linebreak because that's what defines a "line". If you don't want that linebreak, don't select it.

Comment: Correct you are about the triple click. However triple clicking a line is much faster than manually selecting it. What's the point of using an efficient text editor if I have to be inefficient to make it work?

Comment: You don't copy in Vim, though, and that's where your problem is. Triple-click selects the linebreak and there's no way to change that. Since you copied a linebreak you can't expect any program to remove it on paste. You have two solutions: 1. copy what you want to paste or 2. use `setreg()` to remove that pesky linebreak as part of a mapping. I suggest solution #1.

Comment: Also, `p` or `<Shift-Insert>` are pasting linewise if the register is linewise. To force characterwise paste, `i<Ctrl-R>*` as Brian Rasmussen suggested should work better (you're still getting the line break, but at least it will be inside the quotes). In addition, [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Unconditional_linewise_or_characterwise_paste) Vim wiki tip should help you a lot.

Comment: @romainl Your solution #1 is actually the best idea. I've just realized I have this pasting problem sometimes in my terminal too, where I won't be able to cheat with `setreg`. I hope having asked this question will help in making me remember to copy things properly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've copied an entire line (with a trailing newline), Vim uses *linewise* paste, i.e. the text isn't inserted at the cursor position, but in a separate line above / below the current one. With `<C-R>*` from insert mode, you can avoid that, but it will still insert the trailing newline.

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has a `gcp` mapping that pastes the register always in characterwise mode. (And several related mappings for other modes and special pastes.) With it, you just position the cursor on the first / second `"` and do `"*gcp` / `"*gcP`.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. However remapping `p` to `"*gcp` breaks the pasting of snippets with multiple lines. So I guess the easiest solution to my problem is to copy stuff properly in the first place.